# Should I generate a new RSA key pair every time a user is going to encrypt a new file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycryptodome, python-cryptography

I'm working on a project in which I'm going to encrypt some files. I already have an AES function implemented, and now I'm implementing an RSA portion. On the AES part, I created a new key every time I was going to encrypt a new file, even if the password was the same by using different salts. To recover said passwors, I needed to hash together a known password and salt. Should I do the same with RSA public and private keys?  If so, could I apply the approach I used on AES keys to the RSA keys?  Or shoul my approach be different?

This is how I generate my RSA keys:

```py
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA


class RsaKeyGenerator:

    def __index__(self):
        self.__key = RSA.generate(2048)

    def generate_public_key(self):
        return self.__key.publickey().exportKey()

    def generate_private_key(self, password):
        return self.__key.exportKey(passphrase=password, pkcs=8, protection="scryptAndAES128-CBC")
```

This is how I handle the encryption/decryption process:

```py
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP, AES


class RsaCrypto:

    def __init__(self, public_key):
        self.public_key = RSA.import_key(open(public_key, 'rb').read())
        self.__cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(self.public_key)
        self.__session_key = get_random_bytes(16)
        self.__cipher_aes = AES.new(self.__session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
        self.__nonce = self.__cipher_aes.nonce

    def get_session_key(self):
        return self.__cipher_rsa.encrypt(self.__session_key)

    def get_nonce(self):
        return self.__nonce

    def encrypt(self, plaintext_bytes):
        cipher_text, tag = self.__cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(plaintext_bytes)
        return cipher_text, tag

    @staticmethod
    def decrypt(private_key, password, enc_session_key, nonce, tag, cipher_text):
        plain_private_key = RSA.import_key(private_key, passphrase=password)
        cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(plain_private_key)
        session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)
        cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
        return cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(cipher_text, tag)
```

Comment: Generally no, or maybe yes, but you haven't really explained what your application or security model is. You might instead try to describe your use case at security.stackexchange.com since your actual code for generating keys is not really what's of interest here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe it should be moved to security.stackexchange.com along with a broader explanation of what the application and security model are.

Comment: The user should just specify a public key in lieu of a password. They should not need the private key to encrypt (only to decrypt). The symmetric cipher key should be pure random and not based on a password. If the user wants password protection, they should password protect their private key and not the encrypted file.